# How many weekly meetings with a remote worker?

Tags: meetings, freelancing, telecommute

With our in-house team we have daily briefings before we start work and one longer meeting at the end of a week. In time, it's 15-30 min for briefings (mainly 15 min) and 30-60 min for a end-week meeting.

Do you think this is a good approach for the remote worker as well? I know that he should be felt like a real part of the team, but I've read multiple articles where they suggest 1 to 2 meetings a week for remote workers.

Also to say, the remote worker is sending his daily progress each day at the COB which we can evaluate. I am saying this as this may be a reason not to have daily briefings with him.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you think this is a good approach for the remote worker as well?

Presumably the daily briefings and end of week meeting serve some purpose for the individuals involved, and the team as well (otherwise you are wasting people's time).

Thus (assuming local and remote folks fill the same roles), it shouldn't matter if the workers are local or remote - they need to participate in all meetings where their input is valuable, and where they gain valuable knowledge.

So yes - **include remote workers in your standard meeting schedule** - unless their time zone makes this untenable. If the time zone differences are at issue, you'll need to find some other way to communication the necessary information.

Comment: This guy is working alone on the project. So it would be basically myself and him. Still stick to the usual course?

Comment: Agree on most, but some people consider meetings as the worst kind of interruption, and there are alternatives to let workers (both remote or on-site) give their input if needed. Inviting as less people as possible to a meeting (but not less!!) could be a good piece of advice.

Comment: Unless this is an agile shop, in which case the meetings are necessary to fulfill certain ... obligations(?) ... on everyone's part.

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding the frequency of the meetings**, with a remote worker you need a way to:
 - agree on a goal.
 - agree on a deadline for the goal.

Given that, you need to talk with the remote worker each time the current goal is accomplished, so you can evaluate it, and agree on a new goal and a new deadline.

You also need a way (e.g. mail) for the remote worker to let you know if the current deadline is not going to be met because of a particular problem. Then you decide if you need to have an extra talk to set a new deadline or to look for ways of increasing speed/productivity (e.g. proper training).

Depending on the profile of the remote worker:
- For inexperienced people, start with daily goals (this helps to keep each goal simple and easy to agree on). You are already doing this. 
- When someone has demonstrated performance over time, decrease the frequency of the communication (e.g. daily report of advance and weekly chats).

**Regarding the need to feel part** of the team, there are other ways to do it:
 - Each time you make team t-shirts, company coffee mugs, company cards, company pens..., send some of them to the remote worker. 
 - Send her feedback on the team's performance and communicate her the changes on the company (e.g. new hirings).

Comment: and above all, keep the remote worker _in your thoughts_ when determining compensation increases, bonuses, rewards, recognition, etc. Don't over comp them, but also don't forget them because they are not there where  you are.